# Replicating ARIMA predictions by hand and inconsistent predictions

Tags: python, statsmodels, forecasting, arima

I am using the Python statsmodels library and I have fitted an AR(1) model with the following summary:

```
                               SARIMAX Results                                
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   No. Observations:                37581
Model:                 ARIMA(1, 0, 0)   Log Likelihood              -26492.403
Date:                Sat, 09 Dec 2023   AIC                          52990.806
Time:                        14:57:22   BIC                          53016.408
Sample:                             0   HQIC                         52998.934
                              - 37581                                         
Covariance Type:                  opg                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const          0.0043      0.003      1.452      0.147      -0.002       0.010
ar.L1          0.1494      0.001    104.315      0.000       0.147       0.152
sigma2         0.2398      0.000    688.587      0.000       0.239       0.240
===================================================================================
Ljung-Box (L1) (Q):                   0.19   Jarque-Bera (JB):           3751813.95
Prob(Q):                              0.67   Prob(JB):                         0.00
Heteroskedasticity (H):               0.84   Skew:                            -0.16
Prob(H) (two-sided):                  0.00   Kurtosis:                        51.95
===================================================================================
```

To be more precise, we have: `const = array([0.00431239, 0.1493885 , 0.23978491])`.

To better understand how the model works, I wanted to replicate by hand the predictions.
From what I understand, this function would do the job:

```
def compute_ar1(y):
  const = ar1.params[0] # ar1 is my model, its name stands for AR(1)
  coef = ar1.params[1]
  return const + y * coef
```

However, when I run this function on the training set on which the model `ar1` has been trained, I do not get precisely the same outputs. This is the sample:

```
sample = array([-1.87723954, -1.79615098,  0.48589301, ...,  0.0797889,
         0.00951731,  0.34318541])
```

This is the predictions of the model:

```
ar1.predict(1)
> array([-0.27676984, -0.26465614,  0.07625499, ...,  0.01558771,
        0.00508994,  0.05493612])
```

And this is finally my predictions:

```
compute_ar1(sample)
> array([-0.27612562, -0.26401192,  0.07689921, ...,  0.01623193,
        0.00573416,  0.05558034])
```

I have two questions.

**First question:** Why do the actual predictions and the ones that I calculated present a difference?

**Second question:** I also noticed that `ar1.predict(1)` provides predictions that are far different from the actual values (in `sample`). However, if we multiply each value of `ar1.predict(1)` by around `6.93`, somehow we get

```
array([-1.91801497, -1.83406703,  0.52844711, ...,  0.10802282,
        0.0352733 ,  0.38070731])
```

which is way better. Where does this kind of strange phenomenom could come from?
The code which trains the model is here:

```
ar1 = ARIMA(Y_train, order=(1,0,0))
ar1 = ar1.fit()
```

where `sample = Y_train[:-1].reshape(1, -1)[0]` (just to reshape it).